# Why is Firefox cropping circular png Images at the bottom

Tags: css, image, firefox, browser, cross-browser

Why is Firefox cropping circular png images at the bottom of the following page:

http://jussbuss.tv/testing/kpat/contact/

IE 10 and Chrome no not crop these images.

Comment: If you have something graphical to show us, please include a screenshot. It's not acceptable for your question to depend on links to external sites to be answerable.

Answer (score 0):

They are not cropped for me ... have you tried using safe mode to rule out your extensions?